# Video JS - How to change the subtitle font size

Tags: javascript, css, video, video.js

I am working with Video JS, which I am finding really great, though I have an issue since I can't change the font size of the subtitle text, when player is in full screen.

What i have done is to change in the Video JS CSS file, the fon't size from 1.4em to 4em.

```
/* Individual tracks */
.video-js .vjs-text-track {
  display: none;
  font-size: 1.4em;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 0.1em;
  /* Transparent black background, or fallback to all black (oldIE) */
  background: rgb(0, 0, 0); background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.50);
}
```

But it doesn't work, it only changes the susbtitle font size when video player is not full screen.

Can you please help me solve this problem. I am using Video JS version 4.1

Comment: Have you had the chance to inspect the code in your browser when the player is in full-screen? Perhaps there is a different CSS class being used.

Comment: Can you link to an example of this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems that All i had to do was to also insert a font-size in the

```
.video-js .vjs-text-track-display
```

CSS class

Comment: The font size is changeable with that, but I was able to customize further with `.video-js .vjs-captions`

Answer (score 2):

The below code works for me. See https://github.com/videojs/video.js/issues/3301

```
.vjs-text-track-display div {
  font-size: 1.2em;
}
```

See below the full code:

```html
<head>
  <link href="https://vjs.zencdn.net/7.6.6/video-js.css" rel="stylesheet" />

  <!-- If you'd like to support IE8 (for Video.js versions prior to v7) -->
  <script src="https://vjs.zencdn.net/ie8/1.1.2/videojs-ie8.min.js"></script>
</head>
<style>
.vjs-text-track-display div {
  font-size: 1.2em;
}
</style>
<body>

  <video id="dotsub_example" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" width="640" height="264"  poster="http://video-js.zencoder.com/oceans-clip.png" controls preload="auto" data-setup='[]'>
  <source src="//vjs.zencdn.net/v/oceans.mp4" type='video/mp4' />

  <track kind='captions' src='https://dotsub.com/media/5d5f008c-b5d5-466f-bb83-2b3cfa997992/c/chi_hans/vtt' srclang='zh' label='Chinese' default />
  <track kind='captions' src='https://dotsub.com/media/5d5f008c-b5d5-466f-bb83-2b3cfa997992/c/eng/vtt' srclang='en' label='English' />
  <track kind='captions' src='https://dotsub.com/media/5d5f008c-b5d5-466f-bb83-2b3cfa997992/c/spa/vtt' srclang='es' label='Spanish' />
  <track kind='captions' src='https://dotsub.com/media/5d5f008c-b5d5-466f-bb83-2b3cfa997992/c/fre_ca/vtt' srclang='fr' label='French' />
  </video>

  <script src="https://vjs.zencdn.net/7.6.6/video.js"></script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code worked for me, the !important part might not be needed:

```
.video-js .vjs-text-track-cue>div {
          font-size: 0.9rem !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The below code worked for me.

```
.video-js .vjs-text-track-cue {
          font-size: 0.9rem !important;
}
```